# android Jquery Mobile example doesn't work

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I am using sample example of jquery mobile  in my android device. I use this code try to create simple listview, but I don't have result, it is just print like a simple browser, there is no any style or listview. What should I do to fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Intro to jQuery Mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Facebook Friends</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Get Friends</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Post to Wall</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Send Message</a></li>
        </ul>

        </p>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <p>&nbsp; Select an action</p>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: download and keep the .js file in assets folder and give the path , your code gives error becoz ur emulator may not access internet

Comment: Update your libraries. You got some ancient versions in there.

Comment: are u using webview or phonegap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below instructions:

download and keep the .js file in assets folder and give the path , your code gives error becoz ur emulator may not access internet

welcome!